# Watson Discoveryでドキュメントへ任意のメタデータを追加したい

Tags: watson-api

Watson APIのDiscoveryにおいて、Curlで任意のメタデータをドキュメントに追加する方法をご教示ください。
DiscoveryのAPIリファレンスには、ドキュメントの追加、更新の際にメタデータを指定できるような文言がありますが(JSON object specifying metadata related to the document.下記URLのmetadataの項目より抜粋)、具体的な書式については記述がされていないように見受けられます。
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/#add-doc

任意のメタデータをドキュメントに追加することは可能なのでしょうか？
可能でしたら具体的な方法をご教示いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

私の方で検証した結果ですが、APIコール時にfileパラメーターとmetadataパラメーターは併用出来ないようです。
metadataを利用したい場合は、jsonファイルに「extracted_metadata」と記載する事で、metadataフィールドを利用する事が出来ます。
extracted_metadata情報に登録されたデータはDiscoveryの検索対象にはなりませんが、検索結果から取得可能です。

例

```
{
 "question": "Discoveryがつながらない",
 "answer": "サポートへ問合せしてください。問合せの詳細はリンク先を確認下さい。",
 "extracted_metadata":{
  "url": "https://<任意のURL>"
 }
}
```